# Android imageView gets out of screen boundries

Tags: android

I am using `onTouchEvent` to detect screen swipe and change `ImageView` position, my problem is the `ImageView` can get out of screen. here is my code:

**To get `RelativeLayout` bounds**

```
    rlt = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    rlt.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            rlt.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            lwidth = rlt.getWidth();
            lheight = rlt.getHeight();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"" + lwidth + lheight, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).
                    show();
        }
    });
```

**Or other way - to get Screen bounds -**

```
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
     lheight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
     lwidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

**to set the position of the `ImageView` (example of right swipe)**

```
  if (x2 > x1) { // To the right (x1=swipe ends finger position, x2= swipe starts finger position)

                            imageView.setX(imageView.getX() + 50);
                            if(imageView.getX()>1440)
                                imageView.setX(1440-imageView.getWidth());
                            Toast.makeText(this, "right" + imageView.getX(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).
                                    show();
                        }
```

I am testing this on Galaxy S6, width should be 1440 pixels, I checked and the `ImageView`(40px40p) can get to 1333p max and there you see only half of it. I want it to stop at 1283p in this case but also support other phones, universally code.  Thank you.

**Note** - when the ImageView is `imageView.setX(1330)` I can't see it at all but my device is 1440 width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get width/height of viewgroup where your view placed and work with them.

Comment: Does getX() returns the middle of the ImageView,end,or beginning?

Comment: then I don't know why it is not working, I am setting the X to 1390 and I can't see nothing, but my device is 1440 width...

Comment: You need to use for checking `getRight()` not `getX()`

Comment: in my case it always return 171, my image I am loading is 40x40, is there something I need to change in my code?

Comment: So setX will set it to the RelativeLayout bounds and not the screen bounds?

Comment: Yeah, firstly I assumed that you're moving your view in full width layout, but if it's not then use bounds of viewgroup where your view placed.